# React/Firebase how to check authenticated (import or context)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a small react application with authentication in Firebase (firebaseui). I have this file in my project:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<apikey>',
  authDomain: 'mydomain',
  databaseURL: 'mydomain',
  projectId: 'mydomain',
  storageBucket: 'mydomain',
  messagingSenderId: 'mydomain',
  appId: 'mydomain'
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.db;
```

This does work, I exported auth (which is firebase.auth()) and db. Both seem to work, I can access db and auth.currentUser.

I also have context which tells me if the user is signedin:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {auth} from '../../helpers/Firebase';

const defaultFirebaseContext = {
  authStatusReported: false,
  isUserSignedIn: false
};

export const FirebaseAuthContext = React.createContext(defaultFirebaseContext);

export default class FirebaseAuthProvider extends React.Component {

    state = defaultFirebaseContext;


    componentDidMount() {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => this.setState({
        authStatusReported: true,
        isUserSignedIn: !!user
      }));
    }

    render(){
      const {children} = this.props;
      const {authStatusReported, isUserSignedIn} = this.state;
      return (
        <FirebaseAuthContext.Provider value={{isUserSignedIn, authStatusReported}}>
          {authStatusReported && children}
        </FirebaseAuthContext.Provider>
      );
    }
}
```

My question is: when to use what? Because it looks I can just use the first auth object for all my issues (`if auth.currentUser !== null`) and dont use context AT ALL or is this auth object not reliable at all? It should be reliable because you also have the DB object.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking whether or not a user is signed in, `auth.currentUser !== null` is sufficient.

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is useful, for example, if you want to have logic to automatically redirect to a sign-in page as soon as a user's state changes to signed out.

Creating a context indicating the user's sign-in state is redundant.

Comment: So I can just add this logic to the first snippet (onAuthStateChanged -> redirect) and delete the context?

Comment: So, in react, basically I can export values and instances of classes and use them as cached objects. Where is context needed for then? So basically cached versions of files (is this called singleton?) act as cache/context?

Comment: There are several options for managing and sharing the `auth` state. For another example, see: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial#session-handling-with-firebasereact